# Test for empty variable in Swig template

Tags: swig-template

In Twig I have operator *is* and test for empty variable (string or array):

```
{% if info is empty %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

How I can do something like this in Swig template?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply do

```
{% if !info.length %}
...
{% endif %}
```

This will match strings (`""`), arrays (`[]`) and any other object which doesn't have a `.length` property with truthy value.

Comment: Yep. Swig does not have "tests" like Jinja and Twig. There are better supported built-ins that translate directly to JavaScript, like the example given here.

Comment: Hey Paul, swig is really nice and I should have known about it earlier. One question: What is the best way to check if an element is in an array - I would write a filter for that, right ?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if Object.keys(info).length != 0 %}
```

for an object/dict empty test

Comment: Thank you! Only your way worked as expected for swig, whilst `array.length` | `array[0]` returned undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you want to differentiate an undefined value from a zero value in a field with number type, you need to do :

```
//this test will be true only on undefined values
{% if !field and field!==0 %} // note the double = !!. indeed in swig and in js !undefined and !0 are both true values
// this one will be true for undefined and 0 value fields
{% if !field %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if Object.length > 0 %}

{% endif %}
```